# Не показываются метки в objectManager yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не показываются метки в objectManager yandex maps
Использую ангуляр

1. Загружаю карты в сервисе
2. Создаю карту и objectmanager в потомке , добавляю objectmanager  в карту
3. Передаю карту через EventEmitter родителю.
4. Родитель грузит данные
5. Данные приходят родитель добавляет точки в objectmanager
6. На карте ничего не происходит.

Может проблема в обращении к objectmanager , как проверить?

Создание карты

```js
     private initMap() {
        const self = this;
        // TODO ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
        self.myMap = new self.yamapsModel.data.Map(
          "map",
          {
            center: self.currPosition.coordinates,
            zoom: 19,
            controls: ["fullscreenControl", "geolocationControl"]
          },
          {
            yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true,
            suppressMapOpenBlock: true
          }
        );

        // Выставляем опцию для определения положения по ip если не переданы координаты
        if (!this.currPosition.coordinates) {
          self.yamapsModel.data.geolocation
            .get({
              // Карта автоматически отцентрируется по положению пользователя.
              mapStateAutoApply: true
            })
            .then(function(result) {
              self.myMap.geoObjects.add(result.geoObjects);
            });
        }

        // Рисуем метку в центре карты
        const style = self.myMap.panes.get("events").getElement().style;
        style.background = 'url("assets/images/mapcenter.png") no-repeat center';
        style.backgroundSize = "100px";

        // Берем координаты карты при смене ее центра
        self.myMap.events.add("boundschange", function(e) {
          self.calculateRadius();
          if (self.isSetRadius) {
            const newZoom = e.get("newZoom");
            const oldZoom = e.get("oldZoom");
            if (newZoom !== oldZoom) {
              console.log("zoom changed");
              //self.currPosition.radius = null;
            }
            // чтобы не прыгал центр карты в первый раз т.к не было смещения
            if (self.currPosition.radius) {
              console.log("set center");
              self.myMap.setCenter(self.currPosition.coordinates);
            }
          } else {
            const coordinates = self.myMap.getCenter();
            self.currPosition.coordinates = coordinates;
          }
        });

        // Создаем objectManager
        const objectManager = new this.yamapsModel.data.ObjectManager({
          // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
          clusterize: true,
          // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
          gridSize: 32,
          clusterDisableClickZoom: true
        });
        this.myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
      }
```

Прорисовка меток

````js
     showPoints(): void {
        if (!this.myMap) {
          console.error("myMap doesnt exist");
          return;
        }
        this.hidePoints();

        const points = {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: []
        };

        this.tasks.forEach((element: VmFindTask) => {
          points.features.push({
            type: "Feature",
            id: points.features.length,
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: element.data.coordinates
            },
            properties: {
              hintContent: Parser.getTaskHint(element.data.body),
              balloonContent: element.data.body
            }
          });
        });
        console.log("showPoints", points);
        console.log("objectManager", this.myMap.geoObjects.get(0));
        this.myMap.geoObjects.get(0).add(points);
      }```
````

Comment: Можно ли где-то увидеть работающее приложение? Тогда будет проще разобраться.

Comment: @se0ga к сожалению, на текущий момент, нет возможности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в template.
Когда убрал ngIf все заработало.
Очевидно какая-то ошибка с добавлением данных в DOM когда элемента нет.

```
*ngIf="vmSearchFeature.status !== status.LOADING"
```